# Rewrite a dinamic url with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rules

Hello im a noob with htaccess and i have a little problem .

I have this URL mysite.com/index.php/url

I dont have any code to solve this, i search in stack but any can't help me :/

how i can redirect the website when the user enter

```
mysite.com/index.php/packages TO mysite.com/packages ?

Or some other ex. mysite.com/index.php/repos TO mysite.com/repos
```

Someone can help me to solve this problem thank you!! and obviously learn how the rules works!

Comment: # 301 --- mysite.com/index.php/packages => mysite.com/packages
RewriteRule ^mysite\.com/index\.php/packages$ /mysite.com/packages? [L,R=301]   Try it

Comment: doesn't works for me :/ a question how can be dinamically without adding the domain mysite.com and the url for ex packages, repos, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ /index.php?folder=$1 [QSA]
```

And this in your index.php file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['folder']))
{
    header('Location: /' . $_GET['folder']);
}
```

Comment: Hello this doesn't works for me, idk if I expressed myself well, i need that the user to be redirected visuallyin the URL to not only the content of the site, if your code makes this doesn't works :C thank you anyway

Comment: OK, I have edited it, see if it does what you want now.

Comment: Still doesnt works :c the redirect works perfect but when i put /index.php/packages doesnt works only works when i enter /packages

Comment: It works for me. When I put `/index.php/packages/` it redirects me to `/packages`. Tell me if this is what you want. Anyway, have you updated the htaccess code?

Comment: Oh yea! now its works sorry, the problem was de / in the redirect, i changed with ./ that redirect to the same root, hahah! works perfectly! thanks bro! really appreciate it!